# Native linking failed after upgrading to Xcode 11

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I upgraded from Xcode 10.2 to Xcode 11 and encountered the following linker error.

> Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: CTTelephonyNetworkInfo. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo' could not be found in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.

I used the Xamarin.Essential Connectivity module as follow:
`result = (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet);`

There is a change in CTTelephoneNetworkInfo in iOS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/api-changes/ios-12-14-0-12-99-4)
Could this be the issue?  Thanks.

Comment: I did the migration from Xcode 10.2 to Xcode 11 on another PC. This time, I upgraded the NuGet package one at a time.  The issue seems to be related to Xamarin.Facebook.iOS.  I upgraded from 4.4.0 to 5.6.0.  Any suggestion on how to solve this "Native linking failed" issue?  Thanks.

Comment: I removed Xamarin.Facebook.iOS from my project.  Same error occurred.  I re-installed Xamarin.Facebook.iOS 4.4.0.  Same error occurred.  So, it may not due to Xamarin.Facebook.iOS package.  Now, I am unable to build my app anymore.  Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: So when you upgrade the NuGet for iOS Facebook only then this happens? Secondly is this a native iOS project?

Comment: Yes, it happened only when I upgrade to Xamarin.iOS.Facebook nuget package.  No, this is a Xamarin.Forms project.  However, the Facebook login is done completely in custom renderer.

Comment: Dependency Service you mean, Anyway can you give us the link of your Nuget Package!

Answer (score 1):

After troubleshooting for 3 days by stripping down the code, nuget packages etc, the cause of "Native linking failed" is the binding library (dll) created and used in the project.  I just need to recompile the binding library (a separate project) using Xcode 11 and transfer the new dll into the current project.